# datatables {"error":"An SQL error occurred: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'username' in 'field list'"}

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatables

Attempting to receive data from ajax call using jQuery, datatable and php.
I'm receiving an error message :

> {"error":"An SQL error occurred: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'username' in 'field list'"}

when getting back a response
this is my html and jquery code:

> ```
> <table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
> <thead>
> <tr>
>     <th>id</th>
>     <th>username</th>
>     <th>password</th>
>     <th>Position</th>
>     <th>mail</th>
> </tr>
> </thead>
>
> <tfoot>
> <tr>
>     <th>id</th>
>     <th>username</th>
>     <th>password</th>
>     <th>Position</th>
>     <th>mail</th>
> </tr>
> </tfoot> </table>
>
>
>     $('#example').dataTable( {
>         "processing": true,
>         "serverSide": true,
>         "ajax": {
>             "url": "server.php",
>             "dataType": "jsonp"
>         }
>     } );
> ```

this is my server side php code:

> ```
>     // DB table to use
>     $table = 'users';
> ```

```
    // Table's primary key
    $primaryKey = 'id';

    // Array of database columns which should be read and sent back to DataTables.
    // The `db` parameter represents the column name in the database, while the `dt`
    // parameter represents the DataTables column identifier. In this case simple
    // indexes
    $columns = array(
        array( 'db' => 'username', 'dt' => 0 ),
        array( 'db' => 'password',  'dt' => 1 ),
        array( 'db' => 'mail',   'dt' => 2 ),
    );

    $sql_details = array(
        'user' => 'root',
        'pass' => '',
        'db'   => 'autocomplete',
        'host' => 'localhost'
    );


    /* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
     * If you just want to use the basic configuration for DataTables with PHP
     * server-side, there is no need to edit below this line.
     */
    require( 'ssp.class.php' );

    echo $_GET['callback'].'('.json_encode(
            SSP::simple( $_GET, $sql_details, $table, $primaryKey, $columns )
        ).');';
```

please someone help me i'm stock from yesterday

[image]

this is my table structure

"username" column is not present in the table. –  Deepak 31 secs ago

i have a username column in my table

Comment: what is your table(database table) structure??

Comment: "username" column is not present in the table.

Comment: what i'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check $sql_details's db name.

Db name is supercms??

Maybe is your picture's db name right..